# Buttons don't slide down correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 buttons which when i click it, it will slide down the content bar beneath it but when i do the, the 3 others button will slide down unintentionally as well. I wanted the buttons to stay onto the container, so how do i do it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".click").on("click", function() {
    var clickid = $(this).attr("data-panbodnum");
    $("." + clickid).slideToggle(300);
  });

});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #353535;
}

.panbody1,
.panbody2,
.panbody3,
.panbody4 {
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.navcon {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 46px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn1,
.btn2,
.btn3,
.btn4 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.panhead1,
.panhead2,
.panhead3,
.panhead4 {
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #353535;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}

.navbar {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navcon">
    <div class="btn1">
      <div class="panhead1">
        <a class="click" data-panbodnum="panbody1" href="#">News</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panbody1">
        <a id="click1" href="#">Content 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn2">
      <div class="panhead2">
        <a class="click" data-panbodnum="panbody2" href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panbody2">
        <a id="click2" href="#">Content 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn3">
      <div class="panhead3">
        <a class="click" data-panbodnum="panbody3" href="#">About</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panbody3">
        <a id="click3" href="#">Content 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn4">
      <div class="panhead4">
        <a class="click" data-panbodnum="panbody4" href="#">Forum</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panbody4">
        <a id="click4" href="#">Content 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: top;` to div which contains the button and the content `(.btn1,.btn2,.btn3,.btn4 ... )`

OR use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block;`

> **Note**: you could have used just one class and applied it to all the div instead of using for each div a different class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".click").on("click", function() {
    var clickid = $(this).attr("data-panbodnum");
    $("." + clickid).slideToggle(300);
  });

});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #353535;
}

.panbody1,
.panbody2,
.panbody3,
.panbody4 {
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.navcon {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 46px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn1,
.btn2,
.btn3,
.btn4 {
  float: left;
}

.panhead1,
.panhead2,
.panhead3,
.panhead4 {
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #353535;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}

.navbar {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navcon">
    <div class="btn1">
      <div class="panhead1">
        <a class="click" data-panbodnum="panbody1" href="#">News</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panbody1">
        <a id="click1" href="#">Content 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn2">
      <div class="panhead2">
        <a class="click" data-panbodnum="panbody2" href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panbody2">
        <a id="click2" href="#">Content 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn3">
      <div class="panhead3">
        <a class="click" data-panbodnum="panbody3" href="#">About</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panbody3">
        <a id="click3" href="#">Content 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn4">
      <div class="panhead4">
        <a class="click" data-panbodnum="panbody4" href="#">Forum</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panbody4">
        <a id="click4" href="#">Content 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Before you go can you tell me how to make it so that the button box will be close to each other? Because when i have the left border on (border-left: 1px solid black;) for all of them, they will some some spaces or margin between them.

Comment: @MatiasTresch you can resolve that by using `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`...see my edit

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put into this, i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Before addressing your question, you should note that you can make a couple of improvements to your HTML. Firstly, you're *completely* missing the point of classes. They are supposed to group elements together, yet making them incremental goes entirely against this. Give all the groups of elements the same class. You can then use DOM traversal to find the required element in the `click` event handler.

Secondly, you're also repeating the same `id` on several elements when they should be unique.

To fix your problem, place `position: absolute` on the `.panbody` in your CSS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest('.btn').find('.panbody').slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #353535;
}

.panbody {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.navcon {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 46px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.panhead {
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #353535;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navcon">
    <div class="btn">
      <div class="panhead">
        <a class="click" href="#">News</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panbody">
        <a href="#">Content 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <div class="panhead">
        <a class="click" href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panbody">
        <a href="#">Content 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <div class="panhead">
        <a class="click" href="#">About</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panbody">
        <a href="#">Content 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <div class="panhead">
        <a class="click" href="#">Forum</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panbody">
        <a href="#">Content 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```